# How do I prevent concurrent post requests?

Tags: laravel, middleware, rate-limiting

So I have a problem with rate limiting in a Laravel project for a China project. All the users are from China. The scenario is that an authenticated user manage to submit 10 post requests within a second? How can I prevent this to happen?

I have tried using laravel Throttle feature but I am not sure whether if it will work if I set it to milliseconds. Are there any suggestions on how I could counter this problem?

Comment: "I am not sure whether if it will work" - so, have you tried `throttle` middleware? You can make some similar thing using your web server.

Comment: yes i test using a minute but do I use it for milliseconds?